# What is writing to Disk causing eventual Beach-ball-of-death

Tags: ssd, performance, kernel, malware, virus

What is running my machine down? This is iotop output...I still can't tell what is driving my system to a halt. Command+i on the SSD shows my "used space" slowly changing. It does this for about an hour...then freezes. I still have over 112 GB of free space on the drive...yet it yields me a... Beach-ball Of Death...any ideas?

If I listed what I've tried it would be two pages long.

iotop
iosnoop
kextstat
kextunload on all Virtual Box drivers

removed Virtual Box

Beach-ball-of-death

Discovered Virtual Box is not the problem

Created another user...logged in as other user...same problem...

Beach-ball-of-death

Reinstalled OSX 10.8.2 from apple website....

Beach-ball-of-death

here is a gist of the output....

https://gist.github.com/4524724

Comment: Can you reword your question to be more clear what you have tried and what you are asking? Especially the title.

Answer (score 1):

Please post the make/model/specs of your machine, *and **especially the brand, model and firmware revision of your SSD**. I have an SSD that started throwing errors after 4,900 hours of operation. Updating the firmware resolved the issue.*

You can find the SSD firmware by running the Hardware Profile (or more info in About this Mac) and selecting **Serial-ATA** and the your **SSD** in the Device Tree.

[image: Hardware Profile SATA drives]

**Is the problem hardware or software?**

I will attempt to list here a couple of possible issues, and what we need to help resolve.

If you have a second hard drive you can boot from (HDD, USB drive, etc.), please do.

- Does the problem still occur?
- If it does, does it happen on the boot device or still on the non-booted SSD?
- While booted from something other than the SSD, run any disk checking software you have, even if its just a Disk Utility/First Aid/Verify Disk

[image: Disk Utility]

*When did this problem start, and can you peg it to any action you did?*

**Wild process**

Open Activity Monitor. First, click the drop list and change from *My Processes* to **All Processes**. Then click on the %CPU column header once (or twice) so the list shows the top CPU users at the top

[image: Activity Monitor]

*Is there a run-away process at the top? If so, please let us know.*

**Consistency after reboot**

How soon after a reboot does the disk usage start? Do you reboot with the following option checked?

[image: OS X reboot dialog]

If you do, reboot, **but first uncheck the option**.

Now that you're opening with a "fresh" login,

- how soon after reboot does the problem start?
- Is there a consistency with any programs running when this happens?

Your problem can be a lot of things, but from your initial output, I'm less inclined to think malware.

Comment: +10 for the EPIC response! I've done a few of these things already...I'll sit down and take time to respond in detail to this post later this week.